# How to make reuse JavaScript function properties using objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create HTML elements and it's properties using javascript I need to reuse it in a couple of places without writing repeated same code. FYI below is my code which I'm declaring in the object.

I want to use this code for other elements which contain a label, same classes.

```
addNewLabels : function(){
    var selectnewPwText = document.createElement('LABEL');
    selectnewPwText.innerText = "Select label Name";
    selectnewPwText.classList.add("mystyle");
    document.querySelector('.select-new-password').appendChild(selectnewPwText);
  }
```

```js
var resetPasswordControls = {
  passwordBtnInnerText: "Something else",
  passwordBtn : function() {
    return this.passwordBtnInnerText;
  },
  
  passwordHintText : function() {
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
    document.querySelector(".m-hint").appendChild(para);
  },


  addNewLabels : function(){
    var selectnewPwText = document.createElement('LABEL');
    selectnewPwText.innerText = "Select label Name";
    selectnewPwText.classList.add("mystyle");
    document.querySelector('.select-new-password').appendChild(selectnewPwText);
  }
};

// Display data from the object:
document.getElementById("btn-login").innerText = resetPasswordControls.passwordBtn();
resetPasswordControls.passwordHintText();
resetPasswordControls.addNewLabels();
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
  <label for="name" class="select-new-password"></label>
  <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control required" id="Password" maxlength="20" name="Password" type="password" value="" aria-required="true">
  <p class="m-hint">Must use 8-20 characters and one number or symbol.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <label for="name" class="retype-new-password"></label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">

<button type="submit" id="btn-login">Some Text need to replace</button>

 </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have your function receive the attributes as an [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration_function_statement), here is an example of how you can achieve that:

```js
  var resetPasswordControls = {
  passwordBtnInnerText: "Something else",
  passwordBtn : function() {
    return this.passwordBtnInnerText;
  },
  
  passwordHintText : function() {
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
    document.querySelector(".m-hint").appendChild(para);
  },


  addNewLabels : function(element, innerText, className, appendTo){
    var selectnewPwText = document.createElement(element);
    selectnewPwText.innerText = innerText;
    selectnewPwText.classList.add(className);
     appendTo = appendTo || 'body';
    document.querySelector(appendTo).appendChild(selectnewPwText);
  }
};

// Display data from the object:
document.getElementById("btn-login").innerText = resetPasswordControls.passwordBtn();
resetPasswordControls.passwordHintText();
resetPasswordControls.addNewLabels('LABEL', "Select label Name", "mystyle", '.select-new-password');
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
  <label for="name" class="select-new-password"></label>
  <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control required" id="Password" maxlength="20" name="Password" type="password" value="" aria-required="true">
  <p class="m-hint">Must use 8-20 characters and one number or symbol.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <label for="name" class="retype-new-password"></label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">

<button type="submit" id="btn-login">Some Text need to replace</button>

 </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: well! your passing parameters, how to apply the addNewLabels() properties to another text box.

if not mistaken appendTo = appendTo || 'body'; this is not required believe we are already calling through the element by query selector.  if we remove this also it's working appendTo = appendTo || 'body';

Comment: I just added a demonstration on how to make your code dynamic here, so basically you can have appendTo = appendTo || 'body'; removed or default it to anything you want  along with many other things you can add to make your code dynamic and reusable.

Comment: @Durgesh, glad to help, please accept it as answer :)

Comment: small issue tweak needs to do I guess, above code, the element is rendering inside the label because of applying appendChild I believe, below is the output of the code, new element show append after the element, I was trying to add insertAdjacentHTML and not correct it seems.

<label for="name" class="retype-new-password">Re-type new password
<section class="mycustomStyle">New Section Element</section>
</label>

Comment: I fixed like this it works as expected. tks document.querySelector(appendTo).appendChild(selectnewPwText).nextSibling;

Comment: Glad to hear that its working for you now, please [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if my answer was useful.